# Why does this array related code print the index at the end of each line?

Tags: bash, array

I'm having problems working with an array in BASH.   I've simplified the problem down to the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

A1[0]="user1 user2 user3" 
A1[1]="user4 user5 user6"

for each in ${!A1[*]} 
do
        echo -n "$each "
        echo $A1[$each] 
done
```

The output is as follows:

```
0 user1 user2 user3[0]
1 user1 user2 user3[1]
```

I can't understand why each line has the [X] in it (presumably an indication of the element of the array).   How can I recover both the index and the data line from the array without the index appended to it ?

Comment: You need braces. Try `echo ${A1[$each]}`.

Comment: Thank you for this - it was spot on.  If you put it as an answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: welcome.  Answer posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash`*, you have to use braces like this:

```
echo ${A1[$each]}
```

to make `[$each]` a subscript into the `A1` array.

Per man bash(1):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.  The braces are required to avoid conflicts with pathname expansion.

Further down, it says:

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

Which is why your original code didn't work, since the shell only sees the subscript if you use braces.

So

```
echo $A1[$each]
```

is equivalent to

```
echo ${A1[0]}[$each]
```

where the square brackets don't have any special meaning, so are printed as-is.

- And in `ksh`, and in `zsh` if the `KSH_ARRAYS` option is set.